# WS2019 Can't set en-AU as a display language

Tags: windows-server-2019

This should be a simple question but I don't know what's going wrong...

I need to install en-AU (English Australia) as the display language but the dropdown just doesn't let me...

[image]

en-AU also isn't in the latest [language pack](https://software-download.microsoft.com/download/pr/17763.1.180914-1434.rs5_release_SERVERLANGPACKDVD_OEM_MULTI.iso) ISO

The windows 10 language pack [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-10-deployment/english-australia-language-packages-10-0-17763-1/m-p/310105) also is taken down?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EN-AU** is a part of the **EN-GB** language pack.

Once you install this from the ISO in your question you will be able to change this.

1. Download an ISO image that contains the language packs here.
2. Either mount the ISO image or burn the image to a DVD.
3. Press the Windows logo key+R to open the Run dialog box. Type lpksetup.exe, and then select OK.
4. Step through the wizard to install the language pack. Or, you can also use the Lpksetup Command-Line Options to install the language pack by using an elevated command prompt.

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4466511/cannot-configure-language-pack-for-windows-server-2019)